# Is there a reason why empty .json files can not be feature classes or shapefiles when converted?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, python, json

I have a .json file that does not have any geometry in it from ArcOnline. When I use the JsonToFeatures tool in Arc it converts it to a table in a .gdb or a .dbf if not in a .gdb. Any reason why??

Answer (score 2):

If there is no geometry, how do you suppose the tool would know what geometry type to create? No geometry "featureclasses" are **tables.**

The only way you can set the geometry type is if you happen to have a **GeoJSON** file. (See [tool help](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/conversion/json-to-features.htm))